# Error while downloading JSON

Tags: android, json, amazon-web-services, android-asynctask

I'm using my webservice to download `JSON` data in my app. However, there are times when I'm not able to download `JSON` data and it returns a null value. I must also mention that I'm using Amazon Web Service for my server.

Since there are times when data download occurs without error and sometimes it throws a null exception, I'm confused whether it has to do something with faulty web service or my code. I'm downloading data in `AsyncTask` and using the code given below:

Please help me out !

```
public synchronized JSONArray getJSONArrayFromUrl(String url) {
    JSONArray jArray = null;
    String json = getJSONString(url);
    try {
        jArray = new JSONArray(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return jArray;


}

public synchronized JSONObject getJSONObjectFromUrl(String url) {

    JSONObject jObj = null;

    String json = getJSONString(url);
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return jObj;
}

public synchronized String getJSONString(String url)
{

    try {
           URL url1 = new URL(url);
           URLConnection tc = url1.openConnection();
           tc.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
           tc.setReadTimeout(timeout);
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream())),8000);
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           String line;
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                return sb.toString();
        }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Error","In JSON downloading");
    }

    return null;
}
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
01-30 09:55:09.232: E/JSON Parser(18228): Error parsing data java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 09:55:09.232: W/System.err(18228): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 09:55:09.232: W/System.err(18228):    at com.ex.feeds.SetupFeeds.doInBackground(SetupFeeds.java:69)
01-30 09:55:09.232: W/System.err(18228):    at com.ex.feeds.SetupFeeds.doInBackground(SetupFeeds.java:1)
01-30 09:55:09.232: W/System.err(18228):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
01-30 09:55:09.232: W/System.err(18228):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-30 09:55:09.232: W/System.err(18228):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-30 09:55:09.232: W/System.err(18228):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
01-30 09:55:09.232: W/System.err(18228):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-30 09:55:09.232: W/System.err(18228):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-30 09:55:09.237: W/System.err(18228):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat?

Comment: I've attached the log. Please check it out !

Comment: @Infinity This is _not_ the logact, it's the stacktrace. Does your code _not_ run across _any_ of your `Log` calls? -- Can you indicate which line is SetupFeeds.java line 69?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS rarely fail. Do you have a health check and notification configured? Probably not, because you're asking this question -- why not set this up?

Interestingly, you never call `connect()` on your URLConnection, do you? You really should. ;)

Most of the time, before the NullPuinterException, your code should be able to generate a message; which one do you see?

Comment: Thanks ! I tried adding connect(), it doesn't help either. I've attached logcat. Please see if it can be of any help !

Answer (score -1):

In public synchronized String getJSONString(String url)
{......
......
return null;
}  you are returning null value. pass sb.tostring in ending also

Comment: `sb` it out of scope there, dude.

Comment: once check are you getting response or not. And where you are saving response, which string you are passing. By the JsonString(String url) you are passing null value. so its giving nullpointerException. Otherwise befor try block take string variable in thet save the responce and, inside try{} block and outside pass that string variable only

Comment: still, there is an catch without exception log, and a return null. I would start by logging the stacktrace

Comment: once you check sb.tostring. Because you are passing sb.tostring() value or null value

Comment: @njzk2 Please tell me where you see a `catch` without a ?Log? in the code. It's true, the `return null` is irritating, but it only occurs after the exception is logged.

Comment: try this public synchronized String getJSONString(String url) { String response=""; try { URL url1 = new URL(url); URLConnection tc = url1.openConnection(); tc.setConnectTimeout(timeout); tc.setReadTimeout(timeout); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream())),8000); StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); String line; while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { sb.append(line+"\n"); } br.close(); response=sb.toString(); Log.d("response",""+response); return response; } catch(Exception e) { Log.d("Error","In JSON downloading"); } return response; }

Comment: `Log.d("Error","In JSON downloading");` doesn't log what the exception is. could be anything

Comment: print like this Log.d("Error",""+e.getMessage());e.getMessage() will give error message

Comment: @njzk2 Still, it's not a `catch` which does not log something, so the hint where to search for the problem would definitely get us one step further ;)

Answer (score -1):

first take like this public class Quesans extends Activity{JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();ArrayList questionDatas = new ArrayList();JSONObject json;JSONArray groups = null;int i, k = 0;RadioGroup btn_practicerg;RadioButton btn_practice1;RadioButton btn_practice2;
RadioButton btn_practice3;RadioButton btn_practice4;private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private String name = "";private String tid = "";
private String lid = "";private String gid = "";private String id = "";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";private static final String TAG_GROUP = "group";private static final String TAG_QUES = "ques";private static final String TAG_QUESID = "id";private static final String TAG_ANSW = "answ";private static final String TAG_TOPICNAME = "tname";private static final String TAG_TOPICID = "topicid";private static final String TAG_LEVELID = "levelid";private static final String TAG_GROUPID = "groupid";private ArrayList ques1 = new ArrayList();private ArrayList quesid = new ArrayList();private ArrayList answ1 = new ArrayList();TextView txtque;int counter = 1;

Comment: next @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);setContentView(R.layout.activity_quesans);Intent i=getIntent();
name=i.getStringExtra(TAG_TOPICNAME);tid=i.getStringExtra(TAG_TOPICID);lid=i.getStringExtra(TAG_LEVELID);

Comment: name=i.getStringExtra(TAG_TOPICNAME);tid=i.getStringExtra(TAG_TOPICID);lid=i.getStringExtra(TAG_LEVELID);gid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_GROUPID);

Comment: System.out.println("Result :"+name);System.out.println("Result :"+tid); system.out.println("Result :"+lid); 
system.out.println("Result :" + gid);txtque=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
TextView txtRadio=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); btn_practicerg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rdgroup);
btn_practice1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RB1); btn_practice2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RB2);

Comment: btn_practice3=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB3); btn_practice4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB4); 
new LoadQuestions().execute();Button nextQuestion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn); 
nextQuestion.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ public void onClick(View v) {
if (counter < questionDatas.size()) { QuestionData question = questionDatas.get(counter);
showNextQuestion(question); txtque.setText(question.getQuestion().toString()); counter++;}}});
}public void showNextQuestion(QuestionData question) {}

Comment: class LoadQuestions extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
   pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Quesans.this);
   pDialog.setMessage("Loading Questions. Please wait...");
   pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
   pDialog.setCancelable(false);
   pDialog.show();
  }

Comment: protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
   List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   System.out.println("cool");
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tid", tid));
   json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_quesurl, "GET", params);
   System.out.println("ques value got");
   Log.d("All Groups: ", json.toString());
   System.out.println("question");
   try {
    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
    System.out.println("Success");
    if (success == 1) {
     System.out.println("Success");

Comment: groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
     System.out.println("Result Success+++" + groups);
     for (int i = 0; i < groups.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
      String question = c.getString(TAG_QUES);
      System.out.println("Checking ::" + question);
      ques1.add(question);
      String answer = c.getString(TAG_ANSW);
      System.out.println("Checking ::" + answer);
      answ1.add(answer);}
    }else {showAlert(); }} catch (JSONException e) {System.out.println("Error " + e.toString());
}return null;}

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
   pDialog.dismiss();List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tid", tid)); JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_quesid, "GET",
     params);json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_quesurl, "GET", params);
   try {int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
    if (success == 1) {System.out.println("Success");groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
     System.out.println("Result Success+++" + groups);

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < groups.length(); i++) {JSONObject c=groups.getJSONObject(i);Stringquestionid=c.getString(TAG_QUESID); String question= c.getString(TAG_QUES);    String answer = c.getString(TAG_ANSW);System.out.println("Checking ::" + questionid);id = questionid;quesid.add(questionid); QuestionData questionData1=new QuestionData();       questionData1.setQuestionid(questionid); questionData1.setQuestion(question);    questionData1.setAnswer(answer);questionDatas.add(questionData1);}Log.d("questionDatas", ""+ questionDatas);}else {showAlert();}} catch (JSONException e) {}return;}}

Comment: private void showAlert() {
  // questionDatas.add(questionData);
  boolean firstQuestionParsed = true;
  if (firstQuestionParsed) {
   QuestionData questionData = new QuestionData();
   questionData.setQuestionid("default question id");
   questionData.setQuestion("default question");
   questionData.setAnswer("default answer");
   questionDatas.add(questionData);
   QuestionData text = questionDatas.get(0);
   txtque.setTag(text.getQuestion());
  }}}